# EasyBuild ConfigureMake build_step

Tags: build-automation

I am trying to setup and easybuild for an application doesn't have a make step when installing:

```
./configure
make install
```

Running make after configure throws an error. So, the default steps for

```
easybuild = 'ConfigureMake'
```

fail since it tries to run

```
make -j <number of cores on the machine>.
```

after running configure. What I think I need to do is customize build_step so that it does nothing, but putting

```
build_step = ''
```

in my .eb file doesn't do the trick.

Can anyone point me to a method for skipping the make step in ConfigureMake? Or to a method for telling easybuild exactly which commands I'd like it to run at build time?

Thanks,

Craig

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer my own question.

There is an easyblock called CmdCp that could probably be coerced into doing what I want, but ConfigureMake supports skipsteps. This is a list of the steps that ConfigureMake should skip. Since make is executed in the build step

```
skipsteps = ['build']
```

omits the execution of make and all is right with the world.

Comment: Even more 'skipsteps' is *always* supported (it's not specific to ConfigureMake at all)